# ListBox selection that can be clicked to open another UserForm

Tags: excel, listbox, userform, vba

1 of the UserForms(UserForm1) has a ListBox(ListBox1) and in this ListBox, there are 3 items, when i double click on the first item, it goes to UserForm2, when i double click on the second item, it goes to UserForm3, and when i double click on the 3 item, it goes to UserForm4.

Comment: I don't see where is your question? Show us what have you tried and where did you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    Dim Obj As Object
    Set Obj = VBA.UserForms.Add("UserForm" & CStr(ListBox1.ListIndex + 2))
    Obj.Show
    Unload Obj

End Sub
```

See http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/showanyform.htm

Comment: thanks. the code you provided helped me figure out the code i needed:
    `If Me.ListBox.ListIndex = 0 Then
        UserForm1.Show
    End If
    
    If Me.ListBox.ListIndex = 1 Then
        UserForm2.Show
    End If`

Answer (score 0):

These codes can be used (When any item of listbox clicked,another userform opens. The opened userform's text boxes are populated based on listbox clicked item value):

```
Private Sub ListBox2_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Load UserForm2
UserForm2.TextBox1 = UserForm1.ListBox2.List(UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex, 0)
UserForm2.TextBox2 = UserForm1.ListBox2.List(UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex, 1)
UserForm2.TextBox3 = UserForm1.ListBox2.List(UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex, 2)
UserForm2.TextBox4 = UserForm1.ListBox2.List(UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex, 3)
UserForm2.TextBox5 = UserForm1.ListBox2.List(UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex, 4)
UserForm2.TextBox6 = UserForm1.ListBox2.List(UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex, 5)
UserForm2.TextBox7 = UserForm1.ListBox2.List(UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex, 6)
UserForm2.TextBox8 = VBA.Format(UserForm1.ListBox2.List(UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex, 7), "#,##.00")
UserForm2.TextBox9 = VBA.Format(UserForm1.ListBox2.List(UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex, 8), "dd.mm.yyyy")
UserForm2.TextBox10 = UserForm1.ListBox2.List(UserForm1.ListBox2.ListIndex, 0)
Unload UserForm1
UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

[image: screenshot]